# Is there any way to know the RGB values of the colors below a particular value is lighter color

Tags: java, image-processing, colors, ocr, rgb

I'm trying to fetch the text from image using Tesseract OCR and Cuneiform OCR.

However, there are errors in the resulting text if the text is in the small font or the font is thin.

Most of the images we need to fetch the text are having the text return in the Darker color and rest of the image is in the lighter color. So I'm thinking of to convert all the lighter color to white color and then increase the size of the buffered image so the resulted text will be correct. (Correct me if my approach is wrong).

Can anyone provide any information on how to achieve this will be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

If the text is too small/thin for your OCR engine, then there isn't much you can do about that.

If it is a matter of contrast that is causing an issue for the OCR engine, making the "darks" darker and the "lights" lighter is a good way to go.

Below is a contrast formula that I have used before and works nicely:

```
float contrast = 0.2;
float factor = (x*(contrast + y)) / (x - contrast);
```

where x > 1.0 means more contrast and x < 1.0 means less contrast and
y is the maximum value for any color component (usually 1.0 or 255)

Edit: To tell if a color is lighter than a different color:

1. Convert the colors to grayscale in one of the following ways:

> The lightness method averages the most prominent and least prominent colors: 
>   (max(R, G, B) + min(R, G, B)) / 2.
>
> The average method simply averages the values: (R + G + B) / 3.
>
> The luminosity method is a more sophisticated version of the average
>   method. It also averages the values, but it forms a weighted average
>   to account for human perception. We’re more sensitive to green than
>   other colors, so green is weighted most heavily. The formula for
>   luminosity is 0.21 R + 0.72 G + 0.07 B.

2. Compare the resulting values to see which is lighter.

Comment: I realized that I never answered your question fully. I edited my answer to reflect the solution.

Comment: I will try your answer. I got  another idea. Can I consider if R < 125 G < 125 B < 125  As lighter colours and if any of the rgb values are greater than the 125 it as darker colour

Comment: Converting to grayscale will give more stable results than checking the individual components. There are certain cases where your method will define a color as dark but if you look at it, it will be light and vice versa. Luminance is best for human perception and the second average method (R + G + B)/3is probably best for OCR.